# SSRS VB Custom code Converting Decimals to Fractions

Tags: reporting-services

I am using the custom code feature in SSRS which uses Visual Basic and below I use this code to convert decimals to fractions, which also gives me a Mixed number. So I want to change it to a improper fractions. Any suggestions ?

```
***Public Function Dec2Frac(ByVal f As Double) As String
   Dim df As Double
   Dim lUpperPart As Long
   Dim lLowerPart As Long

   lUpperPart = 1
   lLowerPart = 1

   df = lUpperPart / lLowerPart
   While (df <> f)
      If (df < f) Then
         lUpperPart = lUpperPart + 1
      Else
         lLowerPart = lLowerPart + 1
         lUpperPart = f * lLowerPart
      End If
      df = lUpperPart / lLowerPart
   End While
Dec2Frac =Cstr(lUpperPart\lLowerPart) & " " & CStr(lUpperPart mod lLowerPart) & "/" & CStr(lLowerPart***
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the last line to use the `lUpperPart`.

```
Dec2Frac = CStr(lUpperPart) & "/" & CStr(lLowerPart)
```

**Result:**

> 1.875 = 15/8